# Is there any way to use 'unset' as a method?

Tags: php

In PHP, is there any way to have a class method named 'unset'?

If I try to use it as I would any other name, it errors out.

Comment: Why would you want to name a method exactly `unset`?

Comment: It's part of a cookie class, it was a method to unsurprisingly, unset the cookie.  ex: if($logout === true) { $cookie->unset(); }  Either way, I just used 'expire' for now.

Comment: you can find some synonyms word like: remove, clear, destory ..etc...imo

Comment: PHP classes have magic methods, two being `__destruct()` and `__unset()` that you may be able to use to achieve what you want. docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.unset

Comment: I'm aware of those, but this was specifically to unset the cookie on the user's machine, which contained code to set a new blank cookie and then set the same cookie (blank) again with a past expiration date.  The class instance shouldn't be destructed or ended at that time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it from PHP7. Globally reserved words as property, constant, and method names within classes, interfaces, and traits aren't allow on PHP5. `unset()` is a language construct.